# How can I connect my Angular Service to Vimeo? ("No user credentials were provided.")

Tags: angular, api, base64, vimeo

I'm trying to create a service to connect to my Vimeo Account but I'm getting back this response.

I already checked the Client ID and Token twice.

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Authorization Required", url: "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client", ok: false, …}

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseViewService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private configUrl = 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': btoa('****MYCLIENTID*****:******MYCLIENTSECRET****'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
    }),
  };
  private params = new HttpParams()
    .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
    .set('scope', 'scope_list');

  getAnyResponse() {
   this.http.post(this.configUrl, this.params, this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe( response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
}


HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Authorization Required", url: "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client", ok: false, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) (emphasis mine):

> In the body of the request, set the grant_type field to client_credentials; this is required. You can also optionally set the scope field to a space-separated list of scopes. The default value of this field is public.

Example body from the same:

```
{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "scope": "{scope_list}"
}
```

It looks like you're sending a `HttpParam` object up as the body of the request, which does not match the body they are expecting.

```
private params = new HttpParams()
  .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
  .set('scope', 'scope_list');
private body = {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "scope": "scope_list",
};

getAnyResponse() {
  // Take a look at all the extra junk in the param object vs a simple object
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.params));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.body));

  this.http.post(this.configUrl, this.body, this.httpOptions)
    .subscribe( response => {
      console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: creating a simple body Object did not fix it